# How can I have multiple .md files rendered in a single html page of a static Pelican website?

Tags: html, markdown, pelican

I have a home.md file whose content I am rendering in home.html using {{page.content}}. I also want to use content of another markdown file, news.md. How can I access the content of news.md in home.html?

I tried using {% import "news.html" as news %} in home.html but got a TemplateNotFound error.

```
<div>
{{news}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To include a Markdown file at an arbitrary position inside another Markdown file, first install the [mdx_include](https://github.com/neurobin/mdx_include) Python-Markdown extension. Then update the Pelican configuration (e.g., `pelicanconf.py`) to load it:

```
MARKDOWN = {
    # ...
    'extensions': ['mdx_include']
}
```

Now you can use the following syntax to place the target file in the desired location:

```
This is some content in your Markdown file.
{! file_path_or_url_to_another_Markdown_file !}
This is text that will appear after the included file.
```

This functionality is orthogonal to Pelican but is discussed nonetheless in the [Including Other Files](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/content.html#including-other-files) section of the documentation.